# How to go through initial setup of Samsung Galaxy S23 without using Wi-Fi or SIM card with data

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, activation

How can Samsung S23 initial setup be finished with no internet connection - no Wi-Fi and no SIM card with data?

When the phone is started with no SIM card inserted, initial setup wizard page "Choose a Wi-Fi network" can't be skipped. When the "Skip" button is clicked, a popup is shown with message:

> A netwok connection is needed to continue setup. Connect to Wi-Fi, or insert SIM catd and use mobile data.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if it's not letting you, then you probably can not.

As part of the initialisation, it

- does updates and
- disables features on your phone that are not allowed in your country.

There may be other things it needs to do as well.

**One solution is to root it.  But you have to go through the initialisation process first.**